# Parsing yml in symfony2

Tags: symfony, yaml

I have problems in understanding how parsing of yml-files is done in symfony.

I run my command like: `dropcat --env=dev`

```
    public function __construct()
    {
    $input = new ArgvInput();
    $env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
    $running_path = getcwd();
    $config = Yaml::parse(
        file_get_contents($running_path .'/' . $env . '_dropcat.yml')
    );
    $this->configuration = $config;
    }
```

And in my file (dev_dropcat.yml) I have:

```
    imports:
        - { resource: 'dropcat.yml' }
    remote:
      environment:
        server: myhosts
```

My understanding is that the content in dropcat.yml should be imported as well when parsing dev_dropcat.yml, but it does not. Someone who could point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Method `Yaml::parse` is not designed to do what you expect. It just takes `yml` content and changes it into array. It does not *import* anything, so your `imports` clause will be just a key of array - nothing more.

Comment: So, how should I do it?

Comment: what do you want to achieve/get exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Likely you want to put those configurations in parameters.yml, or you might want to add a line to imports in config.yml.

Unless for some reason you don't want them loaded automatically?

Injecting the following line near the top of config.yml should do it otherwise.

```
    - { resource: 'dropcat.yml' }
```

If you want to load different versions for different environment, you can use config_prod.yml, config_test.yml and config_dev.yml.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html

Comment: This dropcat app is menat to be a deploy tool for websites, and all websites have their own default config (dropcat.yml), and the different environments have their file (like dev_dropcat.yml) for overrides from the default. 
Dropcat is meant to pick up config from the directory it is runned from, so no need for default config for the symfony app itself (dropcat), because all sites have different config.
I want to use import because I dont want to duplicate config.

Comment: Then you probably want to include dropcat.yml in config.yml (or config_prod.yml) and dev_dropcat.yml in config_dev.yml, with dev_dropcat.yml.

The key here is to add a more detailed path after `resource:` like `resource: '../../localapp/dropcat.yml'` or something like that. I think.

Let me know if this is what you mean, so I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it without using imports in yml, first I load the default yml (dropcat.yml) and if it does exists, the environment file (dev_dropycat.yml).

```
public function __construct()
{
    $input = new ArgvInput();
    $env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
    $running_path = getcwd();
    if (file_exists($running_path . '/dropcat.yml')) {
        $default_config = Yaml::parse(
            file_get_contents($running_path . '/dropcat.yml')
        );
        $configs = $default_config;
    }

    // Check for env. dropcat file.
    if (file_exists($running_path . '/' . $env . '_dropcat.yml')) {
        $env_config = Yaml::parse(
            file_get_contents($running_path .'/' . $env . '_dropcat.yml')
        );
        // Recreate configs if env. exists.
        if (isset($default_config)) {
            $configs = array_replace_recursive($default_config, $env_config);
        } else {
            $configs = $env_config;
        }
    } else {
        echo "No configuration found for the specified environment $env, using default settings\n";
    }
    if (isset($configs)) {
        $this->configuration = $configs;
    } else {
        $this->configuration = null;
    }
}
```

Could be done much prettier I guess, but it works for what I want to achieve.